# Can somebody explain why I have these options in the corner?

Tags: greeter

After installing some mojave themes, I now have a different lock screen and a cog wheel in the lower right corner:

[image: Lock Screen]

It shows other distros like Ubuntu, which I can log in to. My question is: why is this there and are these actual distros I have on my laptop, next to elementary os?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Those are not distros, but desktop environments. If — for example — you installed McMojave, then a Gnome desktop would have been downloaded as the theme depends on that DE. If you take a look at your install log, you’ll see which packages required which desktop environments, resulting in the download

Answer (score 0):

In Linux jargon, the lockscreen is called a [greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter) and the programs which manage the panels & windows after you log in are called a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment). The default desktop environment of elementary is [Pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#Pantheon_desktop_environment) and its default greeter is the [Pantheon Greeter](https://github.com/elementary/greeter). Apparently, when installing the themes, you also installed the entire [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) desktop environment and its default greeter.

The cog in your screenshot is a part of the Gnome Greeter and it lets you choose which desktop environment to launch. If you're happy with the new greeter, you can just choose Pantheon and log in.

To get the default greeter back, you can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639733/which-configuration-files-should-i-change-for-lightdm-and-pantheon-greeter).